# Upload the latest apk as draft in production

Tags: android, apk, publish

In order to test In-App billing, I uploaded an apk as draft in production. I have made changes to my code and so I went to upload the latest apk. When I upload the new apk, I get the message "Application saved". But the new apk doesnt seem to be uploaded at all. I still have the old apk in there.

Both the apks have been encrypted with the same keystore. I have uploaded the new apk a number of times before this. But I am experiencing this problem for the first time.

How can I upload the latest apk as draft in production?

Answer (score 1):

**Draft** means your changes are temporarily saved and need to be published before they become effective.

You probably want to publish to **alpha or beta testing** in order to test your new functionality on selected devices or by selected users.

Comment: I dont wish to test my app in alpha or beta as of now

Comment: But draft won't help you in testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to Advanced mode on APK tab. There you can move your apk to production (if there is no some problem)